# Mac mail can't send over home WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, email

Hoping someone can provide some suggestions - this one's got me scratching my head!

For a few months now, I've had problems sending e-mail from Mac mail.  It's a hosted account with a well-known provider.  My connection details are fine and they work with Outlook on my PC and Mail on my iPhone.  Sending mails from the Mac just generates the pop-up window that suggests Mail can't connect to the SMTP server.

Receiving mails works fine, so it's not connectivity.  It behaves more like I've got my password or server settings wrong (I haven't).

After much experimentation, I've since discovered that the mails *will* send just fine if I'm connected to my LAN over a wired connection.  It also has worked (intermittently) over WiFi when I've used the connection at my work.

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to set up different connections or passwords in Mac mail depending on LAN / WiFi, so I'm suspecting a weird time-out issue.  I should add that the WiFi works absolutely fine for everything else.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Is your Mac's Wi-Fi interface configured to use a proxy? `System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced… > Proxies`

Comment: It might be worth a look at the prefs - Accounts > Advanced. Check the Port/SSL etc is how you set it & disable 'auto detect & maintain'. Then back to Account Info tab >Outgoing(SMTP) Edit SMTP server list... Again check port/SSL etc & again disable the 'auto maintain'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I've had a look.  @Spiff - I've checked and there's no proxy configured.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I can't find the screen / options you're describing.  I'm using Mail version 10.3.  The closest I can see in Preferences - Accounts is "Server settings" with a tick box to say "automatically manage connection settings".  This is currently disabled and the port etc are hard-coded.

Comment: ah, I'm still on El Cap - things may have changed in Sierra [though based on previous experience, probably not for the better:/ ]